# How to assign ACL to Parse Cloud Code

Tags: parse-platform

I have a Parse Cloud Code function which will create a new object in a Parse Class.  During the creation of that object the parse cloud code function will create an ACL which assigns read access to one user and read/write access to Parse Cloud Code itself.  What is the most efficient way to give Parse Cloud Code read/write ACL access to this object.

I see [this post](https://www.parse.com/questions/modifying-objects-with-admin-privileges-in-cloud-code)which proposes using ParseMasterKey.  I'm just unsure how to grant Parse Cloud Code the access it needs, or if it has access by default.

Answer (score 1):

Inside cloud code

```
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();
```

will grant elevated permissions for doing things like writing to the  ACL object of a DB row you don't have READ permissions for...

sample cloud code doing ACL updates following a query on _Role class...

```
  qp.first().then(function(role) {
     _role = role;     
     if (typeof _role === "undefined") { 
        return Parse.Promise.error(_error);
     } else {
         cst.parent = _role.get("name");
         cst.pid = _role.get("objectId");
         return qc.first();      
    };   
   }
).then(function(rolechld) { 
      _chrole = rolechld;
      if (typeof _chrole === "undefined") {
        return Parse.Promise.error(_errorch);
     } else {
      cst.child = _chrole.get("name");
      console.log(cst);                     
            _role.getACL().setRoleReadAccess(_chrole, true);
            _role.getRoles().add(_chrole);
```

Comment: Robert:  So, what I understand this to mean is that by including the Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey(); statement at the start of a Cloud function, that all subsequent queries will have access to read/write anything even though the ACL of that object did not expressly grant access?

Comment: Correct. The `Parse.Cloud.userMasterKey();` function will ignore all ACLs on objects. Once executed it should apply within the scope of your cloud function / hook.